# Round robin scheduler - call functions periodically at appropriate times

Tags: python

I have a list of functions (1..N) and function `i` needs to be called every `X_i` seconds (X_i would be large such as 1000+ s). Each `X_i` doesn't have to be unique, i.e. it is possible that `X_i == X_j`.

Provided, I generate a list of (function_i, X_i) how can I simply execute these functions at their appropriate times in the future and sleep between calls? I have used ApScheduler before but it runs tasks in parallel and I need functions to be run one after the other.

I can write my own iterator which returns the current function that needs to be executed and blocks until the next one but I'd rather use a library if one exists?

EDIT: N is about 200 at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

## `threading` module

The `threading` module lets you start a new thread, which will not be affected by other threads' `sleep` statements. This requires `N` threads, so if `N` is extremely huge, let me know and I will try to think of an alternative solution.

You can create `N` threads and set each one on a timed loop, like so:

```
import threading, time

def looper(function, delay): # Creates a function that will loop that function
    def inner(): # Will keep looping once invoked
        while True:
            function() # Call the function; you can optionally add args
            time.sleep(delay) # Swap this line and the one before it to wait before running rather than after
    return inner # The function that should be called to start the loop is returned

def start(functions, delays): # Call this with the two lists to start the loops
    for function, delay in zip(functions, delays): # Goes through the respective pairs
        thread = threading.Thread(target = looper(function, delay)) # This thread will start the looper
        thread.start()

start([lambda: print("hi"), lambda: print("bye")], [0.2, 0.3])
```

You can try it online [here](https://tio.run/##dVLBbsIwDD23X2GxSytVFRo3pp122AcMaQfEwRBDI0ISJSlV9/OdkwDbmDjFju3n52fbMXRGL6ZJnqxxAULnCIXUhwaCPFFZCtqDMsaSq/a93gVpdAOCFI71Ep7gjdMDeUC4RhkCAwxSqVSX3WuwLCKe1JrhUv1nzDsS2ZTMfcHoHXHG2RxJlEUxdFIRrFxPS/aKK1BVx@bIxaGjG/wLjKaHHWowNvocHwGFAHQHH8vjTK1X3K/KMzDKx4CRpfSgpCZALRKmYXtLe@OYDetiYEB@Lz@u1zqSdcipLs6oAfeBXFk4Cr3TeUZGX/2il7XwnemVYCQmqhSJiO0DJvEpa8ZcMgxLkDaQ4rcF@MsGfF5BVoFrBhm6BBIGw8P44P9jsww8AdztkunCl7QPOrwb3jBfhukPGd@Rt8SJZwKL0kVp8@HA688FtatkVdz@QIEjD86oTipJf6nMp/OXdNT10qHNUtRlmY21wtNW4BKskzpUs07O6gbuPrcjzepNA@t5@9zAvF1s6mn6Bg); just hit run and then hit run again when you want to kill it (Thanks to @DennisMitchell for the online interpreter)

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer. The reason I don't want functions running in parallel is that each function inserts data into a database. I am using SQLAlchemy which I think will handle insertion at the same time but at the same time I'd like to avoid this complexity. Maybe I shouldn't worry about this though.

Comment: @s5s Not sure - this could cause problems with race conditions. I'll try to make a method that doesn't require parallel

Comment: I've updated my question. N is about 200 at the moment.

Comment: @s5s Okay. That probably shouldn't cause many issues with a modern computer, but I'm working on a better solution. Are the delays all integers?